# Having condition has unknown clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 SELECT sum(pa.depositmade_num) as NumDeposit, sum(pa.depositmade_amt) as AmtDeposit, 
    count(distinct pa.userid) as distinctUser

FROM customer_profile cp 
INNER JOIN player_activity pa
    on cp.userID = pa.userID

WHERE pa.txndate > date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 14 day
HAVING (SELECT (Round(sum(opa.totalhold - opa.playercomps - opa.freemoney 
                        - (opa.depositmade_amt*.1)),2)) > 20000
                        FROM player_activity opa
                        WHERE opa.userID = cp.userid)
```

I have used this same having statement in other queries without issue in mySQL.

However, I'm now getting the `unknown column datawarehouse.cp.userID in where clause` error message.

When I remove the `WHERE opa.userID = cp.userid` from the having sub-query, the query runs. But I need that line for the calculation to work properly.

Comment: You can't use a `having` if you don't have a `group by` before, so this won't work at all. Anyway, why are you using a subquery inside the having?? You are not even using anything from any aggregate function from the tables above.

Comment: @Andres - not sure why you are saying that but it's not true

Comment: @eddd83 - Why are you using `HAVING` here instead of just `WHERE ... AND`?   Try with `AND` instead of `HAVING` and if you still get the error then the column doesn't exist and you should check your table schema